# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0. When I do 'react-native run-android'

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I am giving 'react-native run-android' command to start my react-native app in android studio emulator but getting an error 
'Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.'

I am providing the whole console error below.

E:\reactproj\myProj>react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 855 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
19 actionable tasks: 18 executed, 1 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

  > 1 exception was raised by workers:
  >   java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class org.checkerframework.dataflow.qual.Deterministic found in modules checker-qual-2.0.0.jar (org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.0.0) and dataflow-2.2.2.jar (org.checkerframework:dataflow:2.2.2)
  >   Duplicate class org.checkerframework.dataflow.qual.Pure found in modules checker-qual-2.0.0.jar (org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.0.0) and dataflow-2.2.2.jar (org.checkerframework:dataflow:2.2.2)
  >   Duplicate class org.checkerframework.dataflow.qual.Pure$Kind found in modules checker-qual-2.0.0.jar (org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.0.0) and dataflow-2.2.2.jar (org.checkerframework:dataflow:2.2.2)
  >   Duplicate class org.checkerframework.dataflow.qual.SideEffectFree found in modules checker-qual-2.0.0.jar (org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.0.0) and dataflow-2.2.2.jar (org.checkerframework:dataflow:2.2.2)
  >   Duplicate class org.checkerframework.dataflow.qual.TerminatesExecution found in modules checker-qual-2.0.0.jar (org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.0.0) and dataflow-2.2.2.jar (org.checkerframework:dataflow:2.2.2)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

  > 1 exception was raised by workers:
  >   java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class org.checkerframework.dataflow.qual.Deterministic found in modules checker-qual-2.0.0.jar (org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.0.0) and dataflow-2.2.2.jar (org.checkerframework:dataflow:2.2.2)
  >   Duplicate class org.checkerframework.dataflow.qual.Pure found in modules checker-qual-2.0.0.jar (org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.0.0) and dataflow-2.2.2.jar (org.checkerframework:dataflow:2.2.2)
  >   Duplicate class org.checkerframework.dataflow.qual.Pure$Kind found in modules checker-qual-2.0.0.jar (org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.0.0) and dataflow-2.2.2.jar (org.checkerframework:dataflow:2.2.2)
  >   Duplicate class org.checkerframework.dataflow.qual.SideEffectFree found in modules checker-qual-2.0.0.jar (org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.0.0) and dataflow-2.2.2.jar (org.checkerframework:dataflow:2.2.2)
  >   Duplicate class org.checkerframework.dataflow.qual.TerminatesExecution found in modules checker-qual-2.0.0.jar (org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.0.0) and dataflow-2.2.2.jar (org.checkerframework:dataflow:2.2.2)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:611:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:629:13)
at runOnAllDevices (E:\reactproj\myProj\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
at buildAndRun (E:\reactproj\myProj\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
at then.result (E:\reactproj\myProj\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

E:\reactproj\myProj>react-native run-android --stacktrace
error: unknown option `--stacktrace'

E:\reactproj\myProj>react-native run-android